# Unrecognized options while configuring newlib

Tags: arm, newlib, gnu-toolchain, gnu-arm

I'm trying to build newlib with the ARM option "mno-unaligned-access. I downloaded and built the GNU ARM toolchain from the gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10-src.tar.bz2 package on ARM's website. Then I navigated to the newlib directory and attempted to rebuild newlib with "mno-unaligned-access" but I'm getting an unrecognized error when configuring:

```
$ ../newlib/configure --mno-unaligned-access --enable-newlib-io- long-long --enable-newlib-io-c99-formats
--enable-newlib-reent-check-verify --enable-newlib-register-fini --enable-newlib-retargetable-locking --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls --disable-nls --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/usr/local/test/newlib

configure: error: unrecognized option: `--mno-unaligned-access' Try `../newlib/configure --help' for more information.
```

Looking at the config.log file, I believe the issue is that the target is set to "x86_64-linux-gnu" in the configure script even though the target passed is "arm-none-eabi". "mno-unaligned-access" is not an option for "x86_64-linux-gnu".

```
configure:2297: checking build system type
configure:2311: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2358: checking host system type
configure:2371: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2391: checking target system type
configure:2404: result: arm-none-eabi
configure:2458: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2526: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2537: checking whether ln works
configure:2559: result: yes
configure:2563: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2567: result: yes
configure:2574: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2638: result: /bin/sed
configure:2647: checking for gawk
configure:2663: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2674: result: gawk
configure:4117: checking for gcc
configure:4133: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4144: result: gcc
configure:4373: checking for C compiler version
configure:4382: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4393: $? = 0
configure:4382: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 
configure:4393: $? = 0
configure:4382: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4393: $? = 1
configure:4382: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4393: $? = 1
configure:4413: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4435: gcc -g -O2 -mno-unaligned-access   conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-unaligned-access'
configure:4439: $? = 1
```

Is there anything I could do to rebuild newlib with the ARM option specified? Do I new to rebuild the GCC toolchain with "arm-none-eabi" specified as the target?

Comment: You have to tell 'configure' what the compiler is.  You set variables like 'CC', etc to point to an arm compiler.  If you are on Ubuntu, the 'gcc' will alias to a PC compiler.  You can grab the package `sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi` and set `CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc`, but you probably need more tools and variable to complete the cross build.  Also, this random tooling might not meet whatever your target is.